# Samba connection to windows not working

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I have videos in a windows computer. I want to watch them in a linux computer. Both computers are connected through a router in my house. That is it.

All tutorials that I have found simply say the same thing.

I want to share a folder in  E:\Series. I right click on it and from advanced sharing enable the Share this folder. In permisions I give full control to everyone. Just in case I Add my username (which is passwordless). and also give it full control.

After that I enable the sharing files in the control panel.

Then I go to my linux machine and in dolphin (this machine runs Debian Jessie with KDE) I type smb://my_windows_pc_name/Series and I'm then prompted with a Username and password fields.

I type my username and no password and nothing. I cannot get pass this. It keeps asking me for a username and password and I have no idea which to use...

Any Ideas as to what I might be doing wrong. Also how do I enable the whole file sharing in the firewall without actually turning off the firewall.

The windows machine is running Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't accept passwordless authentification requests for access to shared resources.
Set password for your windows acconunt.

Comment: I tried with the adminstrator name and password and worked. So thanks.